# Помогите понять, почему не правильно работает, пожалуйста

Tags: python

Программа должна создать массив из N (где N - четное) случайных целых чисел из отрезка [-a; b] таким образом, чтобы отрицательных и положительных элементов там было поровну и не было нулей. При этом порядок следования элементов должен быть случаен (т. е. не подходит вариант, когда в массиве постоянно выпадает сначала 6 положительных, а потом 6 отрицательных чисел или же когда элементы постоянно чередуются через один и пр.). Вывести полученный массив на экран.

```
from random import randint

a = int(input("Введите положительное число a = "))
b = int(input("Введите положительное число b = "))
n = int(input("Введите чётное количество элементов массива: "))

array = []
k1 = n / 2 #количество положительных элементов
k2 = n / 2 #количество отрицательных элементов

for i in range(n):
    if k1 > 0 or k2 > 0:
        array.append(randint(-a, b))

        if array[i] > 0:
            k1 -= 1
        elif array[i] < 0:
            k2 -= 1
        else:
            array[i] = randint(-a, b)
            if array[i] > 0:
                k1 -= 1
            elif array[i] < 0:
                k2 -= 1

print(*array)
```

Comment: тестовых данных нет. Что на входе, что должно быть, что на выходе не так? И поправьте текст скрипта - посмотрите, как он выглядит - плохо копировать для проверки.

Comment: а откуда известно, что оно неправильно работает?

Comment: Я здесь новичок, ещё не разобралась во всех тонкостях работы с этим сайтом. У меня код нормально выглядит.

Comment: Код неправильно выводит значения: нужно чтобы положительных и отрицательных чисел было равное количество, при этом они должны следовать в рандомном порядке и не должно быть 0. Мне кажется, что с 0 нужно доработать, а не могу понять что именно

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать гораздо проще:

- добавить в список нужное число положительных случайных элементов
- добавить в список нужное число отрицательных случайных элементов
- перемешать список с помощью функции `random.shuffle`

В вашем же коде в случае, если выпадает 0 или если выпадает уже лишний элемент не того знака, что нужно, нужно было бы "бросать кости" до победного конца - пока не выпадет допустимый элемент, а вы только один раз пытаетесь исправить результат, и только в случае нуля, а этого может быть недостаточно - и ноль может выпасть два и более раз подряд и на перекос в числе элементов нужного знака вы проверку не делаете.

Comment: Почему-то моё 6-е чувство подсказывает, что такое решение мой препод не примет

Comment: @АльбинаБузанова Ну, я дописал в чём проблемы вашего кода. Такой подход тоже допустим, но он не рационален - может понадобиться перекидывать случайное число много раз, особенно под конец.

Comment: @АльбинаБузанова А так то уточните можно ли использовать `shuffle`. Если можно, то оптимальное решение всегда через него. Если нет, то ладно.

Comment: Решение годное. Если библиотечный `shuffle` использовать нельзя, нужно сделать свой аналог.